# Please help to identify connector type

Tags: connector, identification

What is the type of this connector? It has 2.54 mm step.

[image]

Comment: Try molex......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the type.
It is Molex 5264-03 connector.
Part number is 0050375033